# Dynamically changing DIv

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first post here. I'm looking for some help.

I have multiple div contents which should fade in out and out dynamically. I have got this jsfiddle and made it work for 2 divs, but need it to work for multiple, for example 5 different DIVs.

Is this jsfiddle the best way to go or is there a better option. Here is the code. Here is the jquery.

```
   var fadeinBox = $("#box2");
var fadeoutBox = $("#box1");

function fade() {
    fadeinBox.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
    fadeoutBox.stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000, function() {
        // swap in/out
        var temp = fadeinBox;
        fadeinBox = fadeoutBox;
        fadeoutBox = temp;
        // start over again
        setTimeout(fade, 1000);
    });
}

// start the process
fade();
```

Here is the html

```
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#wrapper {position: relative;}

#box1 {background-color: #F00;}
#box2 {background-color: #00F;  display: none;}
```

Thank you in advance, and the link is below.

[Dynamically changing DIV jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3XwZv/)

Comment: Yes, there is a better way. Have you tried to build on top of this to make it dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same code but make it dynamic instead of two static elements:

```
var $boxes = $(".box").hide();
var current = 0;

function fade() {
    $boxes.eq(current).stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000);
    current = (current + 1) % $boxes.length;
    $boxes.eq(current).stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000, function(){
       setTimeout(fade, 1000); 
    });
}

fade();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/637/

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it with CSS3 animations? Depending on your target browsers, this should work well:

Simplify your markup to a single div like this:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

and then the CSS handles all the animation:

```
@keyframes colorCycle
{
0%   {background-color:red;}
20%  {background-color:orange;}
40%  {background-color:yellow;}
60%  {background-color:green;}
80%  {background-color:blue;}
100% {background-color:purple;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorCycle /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {background-color:red;}
20%  {background-color:orange;}
40%  {background-color:yellow;}
60%  {background-color:green;}
80%  {background-color:blue;}
100% {background-color:purple;}
}
#box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    animation: colorCycle 10s 0s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: colorCycle 10s 0s infinite;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CLSc/1/) You can play with the key stops, timings, and colors to get the effect you need.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific application, you could toggle the fade for all boxes and use jQuery's `promise()` to determine when all boxes have finished fading.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.box1 {
    background-color: #F00;
}
.box2 {
    background-color: #00F;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
function fade() {
    jQuery('.box').stop(true, true).fadeToggle(2000);
    jQuery('.box').promise().done(function(){fade();});
}

fade();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/638/